# nodejs twitter how to end stream and start a new one

Tags: node.js, twitter, stream

I'm building a simple twitter stream app using nodejs and twit npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit) this is my backend code:

```
       const twit = require('twit'); 
let tw = new twit({
    consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    access_token: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    access_token_secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
    timeout_ms: 60 * 1000 // optional HTTP request timeout to apply to all requests.
});
       const geoStream = (geoLocation) => {
        let stream = tw.stream("statuses/filter", {
            locations: geoLocation
        });
       
        // ON STREAM EVENT
            stream.on("tweet", function(tweet) {
                
           // ─── SOCKET EMIT ─────
                socketIo.emit('tweet', tweet)
    
            });
        }
    }
```

I have a post route to change location

```
// POST ROUTE
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    // Set country and region from the form
    let country = req.body.country;
    let region = req.body.region;
    // Fetch Geo code coordinates and run new stream
    geoStream(geoLocation);
        //  REDIRECT
    res.render('index.ejs', {
        key: process.env.MAPQUEST_KEY
    });
});
```

twit docs say that

> stream.stop() Call this function on the stream to stop streaming
> (closes the connection with Twitter).

My problem is that

```
stream.stop()
```

does not stop the stream, the stream stay the same, so, how I can stop/remove the old stream and start a new one?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using "Twitter Lite" npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-lite instead of "Twit", it is possible to stop streaming like specified in the documentation
I have create a simple function

```
// ─── STOP STREAM ────────────────────────────────────────     
const stopStream = () => {
        // To stop the stream:
        process.nextTick(() => stream.destroy()); // emits "end" and "error" events
    }
```

then a Nodejs route which starts the function stopStream and redirect to the home page

```
// GET STOP STREAM ROUTE
app.get('/stopstream', (req, res) => {
        // Stop stream
        stopStream();
        // Redirect to home
        res.redirect('/');
    })
```

Now you can start a new stream with new coordinates.